# Running a pretrained model on real-time applications

Tags: deployment, nlp, model, real-time, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to run a pretrained model called "TREQS" for converting natural language to SQL requests. Github link: https://github.com/wangpinggl/TREQS/tree/master
I'm finding difficulties to implement the "app_worker" method to test the model in real-time application.

First, i tried to train the model on my own dataset. It went well.
Now i just want to try the model on some real-time examples.